# Wordpress Schedule post function not working?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a plugin that sent an email when a post is published using

```
 add_action('save_post','my_function');

 my_function($post_id)
 {
  //do everything here
 }
```

its working fine whenever a new post is published or its being updated from quick edit,

but the problem is that its not working when a post is schedule for future publish, for this I googled it, and find the following

```
  add_action('publish_future_post', 'my_function');
```

this is the same function as used for above action,

I also found following action on some results,

```
  add_action('future_to_publish', 'my_function');
```

but the last 2 action not working , mean its not sending any email,

can anyone help me to figure it out ,

Comment: Can you post the actual or relevant part of the code that goes inside the function?  publish_future_post should work.

Comment: okay check it in next answer,

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew Bartel

here is my complete function,

```
  function my_function($post_id) {

   $post= get_post($post_id);

    if ($post->post_type == 'post' && $post->post_status == 'publish') {

     global $current_user;

  get_currentuserinfo();

  $usernamme = $current_user->user_login;

  $email= $current_user->user_email;

  $fname = $current_user->user_firstname;

  $lname = $current_user->user_lastname;

 $disname =  $current_user->display_name;

 $id =  $current_user->ID;

 $user = new WP_User($id);



if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) 

{

    foreach ( $user->roles as $role )

        $user_role = $role;

        $upper = ucfirst($user_role);

}

$email_post_options = get_option('email_post_options');

$adminemail =(!empty($email_post_options['adminemail'])) ? $email_post_options['adminemail'] : get_bloginfo('admin_email');

if(isset($email_post_options['rol']))

{

            $msg = '';

            $postdet = get_post($post_id);

            $title = $postdet->post_title;

            //$excerpt = substr($postdet->post_content,0,150);

            $pdate = $postdet->post_date;

            $permalink = get_permalink($post_id);

            $price = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_meta_value_key', true );

            $date = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_meta_date_key', true );


    foreach($email_post_options['rol'] as $mailrol) // the roles which are saved from the plugin settings page, which is telling that who's role email will be received when a new post from the user is created.

    {


         if($mailrol==$upper)

         {
             $name = $fname.' '.$lname;
            $usename = ($name!=' ')? $name : $usernamme;


            $msg .='Full Name / Username : ' .$usename."\n";

            $msg .='Title : '.$title."\n";

            //$msg .='<p>Content : '.$excerpt.'</p>';

            $msg .='Link = '.$permalink."\n";

            $msg .='Price is = '.$price."\n";

            $msg .='Added date = '.$date."\n";

            $msg .='Published date = '.$pdate."\n";

            $msg .='Total Posts : '.count_user_posts($id)."\n";
            echo $msg;
            if($email_post_options['npemail']==1)

            {

                wp_mail($adminemail, 'New Post', $msg);

            }



         }

    }

}

  } // end if

} // end function
```

its my function , if you have any confusion in this please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

On line 3 you're checking the post_status of the post and explicitly checking for publish, which is only set for posts that (you guessed it) are published.  When a post is scheduled to be published later, it's status is set to future.  For your example, the first three lines:

```
function my_function($post_id) {

    $post= get_post($post_id);

    if ($post->post_type == 'post' && ($post->post_status == 'publish' || $post->post_status == 'future') ) {
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: its not working , if you got me right , I want that 

if a person make a new post and schedule it to be publish in future lets say that after 5 mints, then we should receive an email after 5 mints, will my function do it ?? like after 5 mints the post status will change to published and the there must be an email.

Comment: thanks for your help, I have make it like this, `post_status == 'publish' || post_status=='future' `, not pending please correct yourself, and the last thing I am going to mention regarding this,
there is no need of `add_action('publish_future_post', 'my_function');` mean no need future publish action.
Thanks